# "Extra \fi" errors in equation environment with savetrees

Tags: errors, amsmath, savetrees

I get the `Extra \fi` error for the `\end{equation}` line in the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{savetrees}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
2+2=4
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Why is that? How do I fix it?

The filelist:

```
 *File List*
  article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
   size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
     utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
    t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
 savetrees.sty    2011/05/14 v2.0 Pack as much text as possible onto each page
  xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
  xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
 titlesec.sty    2011/12/15 v2.10.0 Sectioning titles
 geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
    ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
   ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
  ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
     calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 microtype.sty    2010/01/10 v2.4 Micro-typography with pdfTeX (RS)
 microtype.cfg    2010/01/10 v2.4 microtype main configuration file (RS)
  amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
  amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
   amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
   amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
   amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
   mt-cmr.cfg    2009/11/09 v2.0 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (RS)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).   Seems to work if you use `\[` and `\]`, but don't know what the problem is with `equation` environment.

Comment: Weird. The `inputenc` package does not seem to cause the problem. No error occurs if the `equation` environment is replaced by `\[ 2+2=4 \]`. There must be a package clash between `amsmath` and `savetrees`. Since `amsmath` is so useful, I advise you to forget about `savetrees` for the time being (until the issue gets fixed).

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` to the start of your input, and edit into the question the `*File List*` that appears in the log. For me with an up-to-date TeX Live 2012 there seems to be no issue.

Comment: It looks like there is no error when `align` environment is used instead of `equation`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is clearly a bug, and has been logged in as such in the ams bugs list.  however, the bug isn't in `amsmath`, but in another package; see update below.

as reported in comments, there is no problem with `\[...\]` or with the `align` environment.

curiously, there is no problem either with the `equation*` environment, which differs from `equation` only in the application of the equation number.

although it is not recommended to use `align` for single-line displays, if `savetrees` is a necessity, that could be used as a workaround.

i can't predict when an overhaul of `amsmath` will be scheduled, but the bug report has been duly logged and will be considered with all other bugs at the appropriate time.  since the bug isn't in `amsmath` itself, all that will be done is to check that the problem doesn't recur with current versions of all used packages.

**UPDATE:** with @egreg's help, the source of the problem has been identified.

with the newest version of the `microtype` package, the test file runs through with no problems.  these are the relevant components:

```
microtype.sty    2013/03/13 v2.5 Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-pdftex.def    2013/03/13 v2.5 Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2013/03/13 v2.5 microtype main configuration file (RS)
   mt-cmr.cfg    2011/04/09 v2.1 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (RS)
```

this version, included in tex live 2012, will fail:

```
microtype.sty    2010/01/10 v2.4 Micro-typography with pdfTeX (RS)
microtype.cfg    2010/01/10 v2.4 microtype main configuration file (RS)
   mt-cmr.cfg    2009/11/09 v2.0 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (RS)
```

anyone encountering a conflict between `amsmath` and `savetrees` should update their installation with a new version of `microtype`.

Comment: Still I don't get any error; I tried `equation`, `align`, `gather` and *-variant thereof.

Comment: @egreg -- please send me your versions list off-line.  we're using tex live 2012, and i definitely get the reported error.

Comment: The 2.5 version of microtype has been in TeX Live for some weeks.

Comment: Indeed, my installation had the 2.4 version.